# Sci-Hub Download Requests Data

Tags: data-request

I was wondering if SCI-HUB has an open repository for the download request information.

I found nothing on their Web Page nor searching online (I might have missed something on google)

There is a public dataset (http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.q447c/1) from sep2015 till feb2016 but I need more data and more recent data.